# AJAX sends date in data but C# controller does not contain data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I came accross weird behaviour in my MVC site sending ajax request.
I have following call in one of funcitons:

```
$.ajax ({
    data: JSON.stringify({event_id: params.eventId, start_date: params.startDate}),
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("RandomFunction")',
    success: function(return string) {
        //DoSomeStuff
    }
});
```

Then there is this function in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RandomFunction(int eventId = 1, string startDate = "")
{
    if (startDate == string.Empty) {
        //Handle missing date
    }

    //DoSomeMagic
}
```

Google Chrome's Developer tool shows that required data were sent via post request.

```
Request Payload:
event_id: "1"
start_date: "2015-06-08T22:00:00.000Z"
```

But once it reaches RandomFunction, startDate string is set to empty string instead of date that was sent via request and code ends up in **Handle missing date** section

Am I doing something wrong? I can't figure it out for a while.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are getting `eventId`? The example you show has the same value as the default so you wouldn't know if it wasn't being received

Comment: try to do this is controller " public ActionResult RandomFunction(int eventId = 1, string start_date)"

Comment: @MikeNorgate You are right Mike.. even eventId is not received at all

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify`? Post JS object to an AJAX request and check results. Like this: `$.ajax({data: { "eventId": params.eventId, "start_date": params.startDate}, // ...`. Moreover, you have wrong variable names.

Comment: @Kajiyama   Please Put Same Name in controller, which are you send... for Ex    event_id and  start_date  in controller

Comment: you are setting your variables to 1 and '' in your method header so you will never get any other values, also your variable names are different in your ajax call and your method header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example works for me:

```
$.ajax ({
    data: {
        eventId: params.eventId, 
        startDate: params.startDate
    },
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("RandomFunction")',
    success: function(return string) {
        //DoSomeStuff
    }
});
```

And C# code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RandomFunction(int eventId, string startDate)
{
    if (startDate == string.Empty) {
        //Handle missing date
    }

    //DoSomeMagic
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This, Your passing parameter name and Receiving Para Name in controller are different so.. make them same..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RandomFunction(int event_id= 1, string start_date= "")
{
    if (start_date== string.Empty) {
        //Handle missing date
    }

    //DoSomeMagic
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I would expect your problem is due to the use of `JSON.stringify` there is a difference between

```
"{event_id: 1, start_date: \"2015-06-08T22:00:00.000Z\"}"
```

which is just a string, and

```
{event_id: 1, start_date: "2015-06-08T22:00:00.000Z"}
```

which is a JObject that the MVC framework can parse.

Also make sure that the names in the JSON match the names of the arguments